# how to grep and print the next N lines after the hit?

Tags: grep, bash-scripting

I would like to grep for an occurrence in a text file, then print the following N lines after each occurrence found. Any ideas?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Grep has the following options that will let you do this (and things like it). You may want to take a look at the [man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=grep) for more information:

- -A num  Print num lines of trailing context after each match.  See also
         the -B and -C options.
- -B num  Print num lines of leading context before each match.  See also
         the -A and -C options.
- -C[num] Print num lines of leading and trailing context surrounding each
         match.  The default is 2 and is equivalent to -A 2 -B 2.  Note:
         no whitespace may be given between the option and its argument.

Comment: How to do **infinite** matches?

Answer (score 17):

**Print N lines after matching lines**

You can use `grep` with `-A n` option to print N lines after matching lines.

For example:

```
$ cat mytext.txt 
  Line1
  Line2
  Line3
  Line4
  Line5
  Line6
  Line7
  Line8
  Line9
  Line10

$ grep -wns Line5 mytext.txt -A 2
5:Line5
6-Line6
7-Line7
```

**Other related options:**

**Print N lines before matching lines**

Using `-B n` option you can print N lines before matching lines.

```
$ grep -wns Line5 mytext.txt -B 2
3-Line3
4-Line4
5:Line5
```

**Print N lines before and after matching lines**

Using `-C n` option you can print N lines before and after matching lines.

```
$ grep -wns Line5 mytext.txt -C 2
3-Line3
4-Line4
5:Line5
6-Line6
7-Line7
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have GNU `grep`, it's the `-A`/`--after-context` option.  Otherwise, you can do it with `awk`.

```
awk '/regex/ {p = N}
     p > 0   {print $0; p--}' filename
```

Comment: `awk '/regex/{p=2} p > 0 {print $0; p--}' filename` - works, yours not.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `-A` argument to `grep` to specify how many lines beyond the match to output.

Comment: And use `-B n` to `grep` lines before the match.

Comment: And `-C` in `grep` to add lines both above and below the match!