# Print line X lines before/after found line

Tags: grep, sed, awk

I want to search for a particular string in a certain file. If I found the string, I also want to print the line X lines before (or after) that line.

Can this with grep or awk, or do I need a combination?

I would like to have something like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/298123/how-to-grep-and-print-the-next-n-lines-after-the-hit), but not with all trailing/leading lines before or after a hit, only the Xth.

For example, if my input looks like:

```
line1 with a pattern
line2
line3
line4 with a pattern
line5
line6
line7 with a pattern
...
```

I e.g. want to search for the word 'pattern' and output that line + the line that is 2 lines after that, but not the line that directly follows the line with the pattern. So the desired output is:

```
line1 with a pattern
line3
line4 with a pattern
line6
line7 with a pattern
...
```

Comment: `awk` is so general purpose that you can use it to solve your task but you would have to write a script. So, in this case the answer would be _yes_. As you already found out `grep` can handle your task to a certain extent but maybe not all of it. Why do you focus on these two tools but mention `sed` in your tags? Is your real question: _Can I do this only using/combining standard GNU tools without scripting?_ The answer is also probably yes, too, but may be a little more tricky because of special cases: What e.g. is the desired output if the pattern is found in the first X or last X lines?

Comment: @MarcusRickert Yes, the real question is if I can do this with GNU tools without scripting. Concerning the first or last lines: the output is consistent, so if a pattern appears, I'm sure the needed X lines will follow. I will add an example to the question.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081/grep-a-file-but-show-several-surrounding-lines

Answer (score 16):

`grep` will do this for you, with options `-A` (after) and `-B` (before), and `-C` (context). An example I often use is:

```
   sudo lspci -vnn | grep -i net -A 12
```

because this command will show 12 lines after the match, which includes the driver used to control the network (-i net) card. In general, the command is:

```
  grep text_to_search -A n -B m file.extension
```

which will output `m` lines before the match, and `n` lines after the match. Or you can use

```
 grep text_to_search -C n file.extension
```

to show a total of `n` lines surrounding the text found (half before, half after the match).

Comment: Your post (upvoted) is mostly correct, except that the -C n flag is not as you state.  -C n is equivalent to -A n -B n and shows n lines of context on either side of the match.

Answer (score 3):

After looking into this question a little bit I think I have to revise my comment about the feasability using standard GNU tools without scripting. This may be *very* hard to do because of the special cases.

If you don't mind using awk I could offer the following solution. This script `context.awk` ist still rather concise:

```
{
    lines[NR] = $0
    if (dump[NR]) {
        print $0;
    if ($0 ~ Pattern) {
        if (NR-Delta in lines) {
            print "---"
            print lines[NR-Delta]
        }
        dump[NR+Delta] = 1
        print $0;
    }
    if (NR-Delta in lines) 
        delete lines [NR-Delta];
}
```

It has to be called as follows:

```
awk -v Delta=X -v Pattern=PATTERN -f context.awk sample.txt
```

where `X` is the desired "context distance" and `PATTERN` the search pattern. The script tries to seperate multiple pattern contexts in the file by printing lines with `---` in between. So, for example, the following `sample.txt`

```
line1
line2
line3 XXX
line4
line5
line6
line7 XXX
line8
line9
line10 XXX
line11
```

using this call

```
awk -v Delta=3 -v Pattern=XXX -f context.awk sample.txt
```

will yield the followng output

```
line3 XXX
line6
---
line4
line7 XXX
line10 XXX
---
line7 XXX
line10 XXX
```

Comment: Of course, the script could also be integrated into the call if `awk`.

Answer (score 2):

The following `sed` command seems to work for the case you describe which I would restate as: print the line matching my pattern, do not print the immediately following line, also print the line two lines after my pattern, then keep searching for pattern matches.

```
sed -n -e '/with a pattern/ {h;n;n;H;x;p}' file
```

It seems a bit ugly, but by adding additional `n` (skip line, move to the next one) and `H` (keep this line by appending it to the hold buffer) commands you can construct an arbitrary keep/skip relationship following a pattern match.

Note that following the match we initially copy the matching line to the hold buffer with the `h` command. Finally we swap the hold and pattern space with `x` and print the pattern space with `p`. At this point `sed` will continue processing the file line-by-line looking for another match.

A handy reference for `sed` commands can be found [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html).

Answer (score 0):

`grep -A2 <pattern> file | grep -B1 <pattern> | grep -v "\-\-"` works for me:

```
user@box /tmp $ grep -A2 "with a pattern" test.txt | grep -B1 "with a pattern" | grep -v "\-\-"
line1 with a pattern
line3
line4 with a pattern
line6
line7 with a pattern

user@box /tmp $ cat test.txt 
line1 with a pattern
line2
line3
line4 with a pattern
line5
line6
line7 with a pattern
```